# Creating files using Linux

Tags: linux

I am trying to create multiple files using Linux command on my terminal, but it keeps saying -bash: marcel: No such file or directory. Is there a problem with the formatting of my code?

Here is my code:

```
$ touch hello.txt index.html question1.txt question2.txt question3.md <marcel>.info remove-me-1.txt remove-me-2.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<` and `>` are special characters used to redirect streams: you must quote that filename:

```sh
touch hello.txt index.html question1.txt question2.txt question3.md "<marcel>.info" remove-me-1.txt remove-me-2.txt
```